# Can I use a x86 windows tablet for a small utility server?

Tags: linux, windows, tablet

I was thinking in buying a raspberry for a small home utility server , I also looked at intel compute stick (and related products). I realised that compute stick was at the same price as a windows 10 tablet with 1G ram.

What I want to run (for now) is a proxy server which I will occasionally use to access it from the outside.

Can I think of a x86 windows 10/8 as a pc/server and install utility services on it?

What would the TDP and power consumption be per month for a tablet with wifi on all the time and services runing on it?(would it be greater than 5$ per month droplet on digital ocean?)

Comment: In order to have a proxy, you need the traffic going 'through' the device via two network interfaces. I don't know of any inexpensive tablets with Wifi and an Ethernet port. Maybe a USB network dongle I guess..

Comment: Most recent Windows tablets are not the full Windows desktop OS so they won't run most of the server/services you will want.

Comment: The cost to operate a tablet is less that a normal PC, but definitely more than a Raspberry Pi, which under full load would cost (me) about $4-$5 per year.